# Print a Label after the last row of a datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I want to print a label after the last row of a datagridview in C#. The number of rows will change. like this

[image]

And this

[image]

So what i want is to print a label containing the sum of amount in the red area I highlighted on the pics above. What i am doing is like counting the rows of the datagridview and setting it like this :

```
string psum = sum.ToString("#,##0");
int dgrows = dgvmain.Rows.Count * 20;
e.Graphics.DrawString("Total Amount :" + psum, print6B, Brushes.Black, 100, 160+dgrows);
```

And i have counted the sum like this:

```
sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dgvmain.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(dgvmain.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
}
```

I but the above solution is not working in the sense that there is a lot of space after the last row of the datagrid view and as the number of rows increases.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another row with a different style that only contains the summary data.

Comment: Why don't you make an attempt yourself first and if you have problems I will help you.

Comment: I was able to insert the row at the end but its working on when ever the row is added. I want it to be in the end of the row. My code here : DataGridViewRow rows = (DataGridViewRow)dgvmain.Rows[0].Clone();
            rows.Cells[3].Value = sum;
            dgvmain.Rows.Add(rows);

Comment: Can you please update your original post with more complete code so I can have a look?

Answer (score 0):

You can use of gridview footer template like bellow  and set the sum value to lable control

```
<footertemplate>
  <asp:Lablel id="lbltotal"   runat="server"/>
</footertemplate>
```

For more explains refer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972833.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/375489/how-to-calculate-total-price-in-the-footer-of-grid

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/thread8330-grid-view-footer-column-calculation.aspx

Comment: `winforms` vs `asp.net`?

Comment: I am using it in winform not in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

I am about to make this thing (called "statistic") in my project. While using `ListView` (in virtual mode), the solution should be same good for the `DataGridView` methink. You have to make a component (control), what will *mimics* headers of bound to it control and automatically takes either selection or the whole number of rows and calculate statistic. It may be possible to provide sort of info for this control via `Header.Tag`:

```
if(header.Tag is INoStatistic) { /* do nothink */ }
```

Advantage of such method compared to use of the ordinal row is what your statistic is always visible (sort of a "frozen column" or as @Ramakrishna.p just posted, a footer) and you can use it with any `DataGridView` in the future.

I'll update my answer when I am done with (if interested), or maybe you will finish first? =D